# In SQL, trying to return a record for each instance where it triggers the from criteria

Tags: sql

Maybe I'm looking at this problem all wrong, but here goes.

We have a database that is the backend for some CRM software we use in the office. The boss wants a simple query to extract birthdays from clients and their spouses.

The table structure is as follows:

```
Client Details Table:
Client Name, Client Birthday, Spouse Name, Spouse Birthday, <etc>
```

I have a simple query with a case select that will determine if the client's birthday or the spouse's birthday is any time in the next month.

Query is compacted as follows:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
  (SELECT
     (CASE    WHEN <birthday calculation>
              ELSE NULL 
      END) as WhoHasBDay,
      ClientName,
      SpouseName
   FROM
     ClientDetailsTable) as a
WHERE
   a.WhoHasBDay IS NOT NULL
```

This will return any entries where the client or the spouse has a birthday in the next X days.

However, if a client AND their spouse has a birthday in the next X days, I would like the query to return the result once for each.

IE, here is the following data

```
CLIENT X: Birthday in 5 days
CLIENT Y: Spouse's Birthday in 8 days
CLIENT Z: Birthday in 3 days, Spouse's Birthday in 9 days.
```

The result set I want is

```
CLIENT X BDAY T+5
CLIENT Y SPOUSE BDAY T+8
CLIENT Z BDAY T+3
CLIENT Z SPOUSE BDAY T+9
```

Perhaps I'm approaching this problem the wrong way, in which case suggestion on a better method of attacking it would be appreciated. Otherwise if there's a solution to this, please let me know.

Comment: SQL Server, mySQL, DB2, Oracle... which are you using?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd tackle this as a UNION of two separate queries: one for clients and one for their spouses.

```
SELECT ClientName, NULL AS SpouseName, Birthday
    FROM ClientDetailsTable
    WHERE <birthday calculation is true>
UNION ALL
SELECT ClientName, SpouseName, SpouseBirthday
    FROM ClientDetailsTable
    WHERE <spouse birthday calculation is true>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was lightning quick and right on. I feel dumb for making it more complicated than I had to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Union the two queries together:

```
 SELECT ClientName, ClientName AS BirthdayPerson, ClientBirthday FROM Clients 
    WHERE ClientBirthday BETWEEN X AND Y
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT ClientName, SpouseName AS BirthdayPerson, SpouseBirthday FROM Clients 
    WHERE SpouseBirthday BETWEEN X AND Y
```

This will give you every person with a birthday between dates X and Y (you can change the birthday calculation however you want).

Comment: As with the other solutions, thanks for the quick response. I appreciate it very much. Definitely rolled out a variant on this and got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the "union" in sql like so:

select * from ClientDetailsTable where "client has birthday" union all

select * from clientDetailsTable where "Spouse has birthday"

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code in sql server.  Give you the most recent first of both birthday types in the next 16 days.

```
SELECT ClientName, ClientBirthday, null as SouseBirthday, ABS(DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),ClientBirthday)) as days
FROM ClientDetailsTable
WHERE ClientBirthday BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(day,16,ClientBirthday)
UNION ALL
SELECT ClientName, null as ClientBirthday, SouseBirthday, ABS(DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),SouseBirthday)) as days
FROM ClientDetailsTable
WHERE SouseBirthday BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(day,16,SouseBirthday)
ORDER BY days asc
```

NB, not tested might have typos.

Comment: Thanks a million, you and Joe were very helpful. Much obliged. Shame I can't mark both as answers and don't have the rep to be able to upvote you two. Much obliged.

Comment: @AJQuad I'm looking forward to the up-vote once you have the rep.